# How to edit few fields in a list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

I have created a site definition using list and I am trying to edit few list fields in sharepoint 2010. I am able to edit all the fields present in the list using EditForm.aspx. I am opening this form in a popup. Now the problem is that I don't want to edit all the fields. I want only few fields to be edited.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Open the *editform.aspx* using **script webpart**, then disable the form field by using the javascript. It sounds easy...

Comment: Hi Srinivasan, Thanks for you answer. The thing is I am opening the editform.aspx using a javascript but that's not in the CEWP. Can you please let me know some example which do the same kind of thing..

Comment: You can open the editform.aspx using CEWP and make the javascript to disable the fields... Its more easier...